# How to get the filename without the date part in Python?

Tags: python, string

the filename can be any of below examples

```
abc_dec_2020_06_23.csv
efg_edd_20200623.csv
abc_20200623121935.csv
```

I need to extract only by excluding the number part

```
abc_dec_
efg_edd
abc_
```

I am trying to achieve the archive the previous file present in the SFTP location

Below is what I am trying to achieve

```
fileName = self.s3_key.split('/')[-1]
sftp_client.rename( self.sftp_path + fileName,  archive_path + fileName)
 with sftp_client.open(self.sftp_path + fileName, 'wb') as f:
        s3_client.download_fileobj(self.s3_bucket, self.s3_key, f)
```

Comment: what did you try so far?
perhaps you have some ideas how you;d like to do it and then we can give you pointers?



you might look at `os.path.split` and at `re` 

could you have files with names like `file_number_1_2020_06_23.csv` or are you sure you have never digits in the first part.

Comment: I have actually tried `os.path.splitext("VBC_UP_20200601.csv")[0]`  .. Agree with you some filename can have a number in b/w but always has a date at the end. I am actually trying to archive the file in sftp location before I can upload the new file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
file='abc_dec_2020_06_23.csv'
cleanfile=''
for let in file:
    if let.isdigit():
        break
    else:
        cleanfile+=let
  

print(cleanfile)
```

Output:

```
'abc_dec_'
```

And if your filenames have digits, you can try this:

```
x='abc_12_dec_2020_06_23.csv'
newval=''
for i,val in enumerate(x.split('_')):
    if i==len(x.split('_'))-1:
        if len(val.replace('.csv',''))<8 and len(list(x.split('_'))[i-1])>2: #e.g. 202006_23.csv'
            newval='_'.join(list(x.split('_'))[:i-1])+'_'
        elif len(val.replace('.csv',''))<8 and len(list(x.split('_'))[i-1])==2: #e.g. 2020_06_23.csv'
            newval='_'.join(list(x.split('_'))[:i-2])+'_'
        elif len(val.replace('.csv',''))<8 and len(val.replace('.csv',''))==4: #e.g. 2020_0623.csv'
            newval='_'.join(list(x.split('_'))[:i-1])+'_'
        else:
            newval='_'.join(list(x.split('_'))[:i])+'_'
print(newval)
```

Output:

```
'abc_12_dec_'
```

Comment: this approach assumes, that the first part of the file name never contains digits, not even a single one.

Comment: That's a quick reply, appreciate it .. I don't get a list of files but only one filename and get the part of it .. Above was an example

Comment: Basically I want to archive the file , as always the filename will have datepart in the end .. so wanted to do wildcard to archive that file

Comment: Sure, the second for loop will archieve that. But gelonida it's right, this will ignore all the digits in the filename... @Kar the filename could have digits before the date?

Comment: See my edit, I'm assuming that the date is always at the end and that could have the forms of: ` '2020_0623.csv','2020_06_23.csv','202006_23.csv' `. Hope it works for you:).

Answer (score 2):

With a regular expression:

```
r"^[a-z_]+"
```

Example:

```
import re
regex_comp = re.compile(r"^[a-z_]+")
match_str = regex_comp.match("abc_20200623121935.csv")
print(match_str.group())
```

Result:

```
abc_
```

If your filenames have digits:

```
import re
filenames = ["efg_12_edd_20200623.csv", "abc_dec_2020_06_23.csv",
             "efg_edd_20200623.csv", "a1b2c11_20200623121935.csv"]

regex1 = re.compile(r"[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}\.csv$")
regex2 = re.compile(r"[0-9]{8,14}\.csv$")

filename = ""
for filename_full in filenames:
    test = regex1.search(filename_full)
    if test is None:
        test = regex2.search(filename_full)
    if test is not None:
        filename = filename_full[:test.span()[0]]
        print(filename)
    else:
        print(filename_full, ": No match")
```

Result:

```
efg_12_edd_
abc_dec_
efg_edd_
a1b2c11_
```

Comment: As gelonida says in my answer below: "this approach assumes, that the first part of the file name never contains digits, not even a single one."

Comment: Yes, if the left side of the filename has numbers this approach will not work. As an alternative you can use three regex to match the **date** part and use the result to remove the final part.

Comment: Nice approach with regex .  Although this wouldn't work with abc_dec_2020_0623.csv, if hypothetically the filename was like this, who knows, your answer is great .

Comment: @MrNobody33 when the pattern is unknown or foggy you can create a cascade of regex (or even a more complex regex) to cover most of patterns. If all of the regex fail you end in a "no match, sorry" and continue or quit.

Comment: Yeah, that's true.